# Automate data transforming ( SQL) and then push processed data to Tableau

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, etl, analysis

I have questions about ways to automate data transformation process.

What I normally do is that I transform data using python or postgresql and then export the processed data as csv. After that, I connect the csv file to Tableau.

I have done some research and found that ETL can help. However, I've watched some ETL tools' demo videos, and I'm not sure whether these tools' transform features would meet my need or not. For example, I have written 100+ sql lines for one of my data transforming task; it's better if I can use postgresql to run the query instead of using ETL tools.

The problem is that I don't know what's the proper way to automate the data transforming process and then push the data to Tableau. The csv files will be updated on a daily basis, so I'll need to refresh the data.

Answer (score 0):

Data transformation can be done in various ways. It depends on your nature of data to figure out what can be the right fit.

If you have huge volume of data and you are comfortable in python/java and you can automate your transformation logic using spark and write it to a hive table and then connect tableau to read data from hive.

Most of the next gen ETL tools like pentaho and talend can be used but that erodes the flexibility and portability what a framework like spark or beam can give.

If you want to know , how can you achieve this using cloud provider services like GCP or AWS , please let me know

Answer (score 0):

[Prep](https://www.tableau.com/products/prep) is the Tableau tool for preparing data. It can be used for joining, appending, cleaning, pivoting, filtering and other data cleansing activities.

Tableau Prep is available:

- for free if you have a Tableau Creator license
- in desktop and Online/ Tableau server versions

Scheduling Prep flows is available in Tableau Online/ Server. To schedule flows you will need to acquire the Tableau Prep Conductor add-on.